# calculate monthly mean, 90th and 99th percentile of time series

Tags: matlab

I'm reading this article on wind speed trends and they specify in their methods that they tried to determine if there is a trend within the time series of monthly mean, 90th, and 99th percentile values of wind speed over the period shown. How would one achieve this? Furthermore, what does it mean by 90th and 99th percentile? My example:

```
v = datenum(1981, 1, 1):datenum(2010, 11, 31); % time vector
d = rand(1,length(v)); % data vector

% calculate mean, 90th and 99th percentile values
dateV = datevec(v); % date vector
[~,~,b] = unique(dateV(:,1:2),'rows');
monthly_v = accumarray(b,v,[],@mean);
monthly_d = accumarray(b,d,[],@mean);
```

I can calculate the monthly mean by the method shown above, but am not sure on how to calculate the 90th and 99th percentile (plus I'm not even sure what it is). Can anyone provide some information on this?

Comment: Say there are 100 students taking an exam, the average was 80, the highest was 95. 90th percentile refers to 10 percent of students got better score than this value, and 89 percent of students got worse scores. to calculate this, you can use the Matlab percentile Y = prctile(X,p) where X is your data distribution, p is the percentile you are looking for, Y returns the Value (i.e. test score) of that percentile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`prctile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prctile.html) function.  What you are seeking is a threshold where the proportion / percentage of input data that is exceeding this threshold is `100% - percentile`.  For example, if you sought the 90% quantile, you are trying to find a quantity in your input data where 10% of your data exceeded this quantity.  For the 99% percentile, you are seeking the quantity in your input data where 1% of your data exceeded this threshold.  You can simply call `prctile` by:

```
Y = prctile(X, P);
```

`X` is your data stored in vector form, and `P` is a vector or single number that lists the percentiles you desire.  The output would be those thresholds that we just talked about, stored in `Y`.

In your case, `v` and `d` is your data you want to find the percentiles on per month, and thus you would modify your `accumarray` call like so:

```
monthly_v_90 = accumarray(b,v,[],@(x) prctile(x, 90));
monthly_v_99 = accumarray(b,v,[],@(x) prctile(x, 99));
monthly_d_90 = accumarray(b,d,[],@(x) prctile(x, 90));
monthly_d_99 = accumarray(b,d,[],@(x) prctile(x, 99));
```

What the above code will do is that for each unique month, you will calculate the 90% and 99% quantiles for `v` and `d` respectively.  Specifically, `monthly_v_90` and `monthly_v_99` will give you the 90% and 99% quantiles for each month in a unique year for `v` while `monthly_d_90` and `monthly_d_99` will give you the 90% and 99% quantiles for each month in a unique year for `d`.

In your call to `datevec`, you are generating months from January 1981 to December 2010.  Because there are 30 years in between, and there are 12 months in a year, you should have 360 element vectors with the above (as well as your calculations for the mean).